# htmlspecialchars or mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, function

I am unsure which one to use in this situation???

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE 
messages.custid='".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['customerid'])."' 
ORDER BY messages.id LIMIT $start, $limit ";
```

Comment: thats ridiculous. http://stackoverflow.com/users/342391/user342391 - note top 5 questions

Comment: Eyelids or feet, I'm not sure which to use to walk to the store...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mysql_real_escape_string .. But really, don't do that

instead, install Pear's PDO library, then use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for your query

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string() is made especialy for Mysql Tables, as the name indicates ;-)