# Difference between htmlspecialchars and mysqli_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql

I read in a PHP book that it is a good practice to use `htmlspecialchars` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` in conditions when we handle user inputed data. What is the main difference between these two and where they are appropriate to be used? Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htmlspecialchars or mysql_real_escape_string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603146/htmlspecialchars-or-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

htmlspecialchars: "<" to "& lt;"
(Replaces HTML-Code)

mysqli_real_escape_string: " to \"
(Replaces Code, that has a meaning in a mysql-query)

Both are used to be save against some attacks like SQL-Injection and XSS

Comment: Can you kindly explain it with an example

Comment: htmlspecialchars("< b >ä< /b >") == "& lt; b & lt;&auml; & lt; /b & gr;"

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string (") [imagine the qoutes around] == \",

Answer (score 10):

These two functions are used for completely different things.

htmlspecialchars() converts special HTML characters into entities so that they can be outputted without problems. mysql_real_escape_string() escapes sensitive SQL characters so dynamic queries can be performed without the risk of SQL injection.

You could just as easily say that htmlspecialchars handles sensitive OUTPUT, while mysql_real_escape_string handles sensitive INPUT.

Shai

Comment: Can you kindly explain it with an example

Comment: I think @EGOrecords already explained it. Also i recommend reading the manual as it has all the needed examples: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars , http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 7):

The two functions are totally unrelated in purpose; the only attribute they share is that they are commonly used to provide safety to web applications.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` is meant to provide safety against [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/50079).

`htmlspecialchars` is meant to provide safety against cross-site scripting (XSS).

Also see [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129677/50079) and [Do htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string keep my PHP code safe from injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575)

Comment: Can you kindly explain it with an example

Comment: @TheNoble-Coder: Look at the questions I link to. Also, google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

htmlspecialcharacters turns 'html special characters' into code, such as quotes (both single and double), ampersands, and less than/greater than signs.  This function is generally used to ensure that content users post on your website doesn't have HTML tags or XSS scripts.

mysql_real_escape_string escapes strings, meaning it adds the \ in front of slashes, quotes(both single and double), and anything else that can mess up a mysql query. This function ensures that no one is executing SQL commands on your server and getting information from the database.

Comment: Can you kindly explain it with an example

Answer (score 1):

### When to use real_escape_string?

Short: Use when building queries which depend on user submitted data.

Long:
When saving user submitted data to your database in a manner which does not use prepared statements (these are escaped by default). What it does is prevent situations as the following

(**DO NOT DO THIS**):

`txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + $_GET("userid");`

Using real_escape_string($_GET("userid") instead of the raw parameter prevents that an attacker gets all users sending a userid parameter which is formed like this: '100 OR 1=1'. This would be concatenated and yield the query:

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 100 OR 1=1;`

Which would return all users data in the database.

Real escape string would escape 100 OR 1=1 in a way that it would not be interpreted as valid SQL and thus would not yield all user data.

[More on SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

### When to use htmlspecialchars?

Short: Use when echoing user submitted data to your page.

Long: If user manages to save a string like:

`<script>alert("Stealing your cookies")</script>`

to your database which is then presented to other users and you echo it without htmlspecialchars [the javascript code in the script tag would execute on the users machine](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/), which is just bad news, as now pretty much any data within the browser could be stolen (cookies/localstorage) or the user be redirected.

The resulting string of htmlspecial chars on the aforementioned script tag would be:

`&lt;script&gt;alert('Stealing your cookies')'&lt;/script&gt;`

Which would be displayed on the page and not be interpreted as javascript code.